# Validate the `IAntiforgeryValidationFeature` on the request before reading from the form

Tags: asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-identity

I have a Blazor server web application set up using asp.net core identity, when i log in everything is fine but if i log out i get this error:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: This form is being accessed with an invalid anti-forgery token. Validate the `IAntiforgeryValidationFeature` on the request before reading from the form.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.HandleUncheckedAntiforgeryValidationFeature()

Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing
InvalidOperationException: This form is being accessed with an invalid anti-forgery token. Validate the `IAntiforgeryValidationFeature` on the request before reading from the form.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.HandleUncheckedAntiforgeryValidationFeature()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.ReadForm()
lambda_method77(Closure , object , HttpContext , object )
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory+<>c__DisplayClass104_2+<b__2>d.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.AntiforgeryMiddleware.InvokeAwaited(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

I have tried to add     @Html.AntiForgeryToken() to the form although it does not recognise @Hmtml

Answer (score 0):

> Blazor endpoints now require antiforgery protection by default. You
> can enable antiforgery support using the new antiforgery middleware
> and using the AntiforgeryToken component to generate tokens for
> rendered forms. The EditForm component will add the antiforgery token
> automatically for you.

Add the AntiforgeryToken component like:

```
   <form>
        <AntiforgeryToken />
    </form>
```

And add

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery;
@attribute [RequireAntiforgeryToken]
```

Besides, try to set `app.UseAntiforgery()` after `app.UseAuthentication()`.

You can have a look at [Blazor
Antiforgery integration](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-8-preview-7/#blazor) to know more.